# Replacing Values in a dataframe using a list to identify rows that need to be changed

Tags: python, list, loops, replace

I have a list of id's I have extracted from a bigger data set that I am cleaning. Long story short, all the denominator numbers need to be 10 and there are some that are much bigger, probably from typos. I need loop through that list of id's to compare against the original data set and change the incorrect values to 10. I have tried a couple different things but keep getting errors. Both the list elements and the original elements are both type string, so I know I am not comparing different data types. See below:

```
denominator_cleaning_list = ['832088576586297345', '820690176645140481',
 '775096608509886464', etc]

for element in denominator_cleaning_list:
    cleaning_df.loc[element, 'rating_denominator'] == 10
```

Thats the jist of what I am attempting to do. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Use vectorial code:

```
cleaning_df.loc[cleaning_df.index.isin(denominator_cleaning_list), 'rating_denominator'] = 10
```

Comment: Thank you for responding. I tried your solution and when I check the dataframe to see if the values changed, they did not change. Do I need to add something like 'inplace=True'?

Comment: No you shouldn't have to. Maybe give more details in the question. Provide a minimal reproducible input and the matching expected output.

Comment: Likely the denominator_cleaning_list did not match anything in the index. First thing I would check is that they are the same dtype. Or, in your question you have "==" for the assignment, which is wrong. Did you use a single "=" when you tried it?

Comment: I think you can just do `cleaning_df.loc[denominator_cleaning_list, 'rating_denominator'] = 10`. The "isin" check isn't necessary as it's checking the index, not the values in a column.

Comment: I screwed up the '==', I had '='. Datatypes are the same. When I added the second '=' it worked fine. Thank you all!

Comment: @Colin it depends if you have extra values in the list, you could risk an `IndexError` ;)